# How to increase number of build queue in Hudson?

Tags: hudson

i want to know is it possible to increase the number of `build queue` in Hudson?

i m using `Hudson version 1.395.1`

Currently only 2 queue are provided but in my case, i have 6 environment managed with hudson. so i need to have more than 2 `build queue` number.

Answer (score 0):

We only have a Jenkins but it should be similar. In the configuration menu there is an option almost at the top. Should be called something like "number of build processes". Can't say exactly because our Jenkins is also German ;-)

Sorry for the unspecific answer but maybe it helps.

Comment: in Hudson, there are no term **number of build processes**, but it has **#of Executors** and its mean the number for execution, not the build queue.

Comment: Thought that was what you meant with build queue because in never experienced that the queue is actually limited. Sorry!